# How to get the Delannoy Number Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The Delannoy path is a set of paths from (0, 0) to (m, n) using only steps (1, 0), (1, 1) or (0, 1). I know the generating function is $\frac{1}{1-x-y-xy}$

So far Im given, 
D(x, y) = $\sum_{m \geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0} d_{m,n}x^{m}y^{n}$ and I know $d_{m,n}$ = D(m-1, n) + D(m-1, n-1), D(m, n-1).

What properties should I use to go from the recursion, to the generating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

$\begin{array}\\
d(x, y)
&=\sum_{m \geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0} d(m,n)x^{m}y^{n}\\
&=-d(0, 0)+\sum_{n \geq 0} d(0,n)y^{n}
+\sum_{m \geq 0} d(m,0)x^{m}
 +\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1} d(m,n)x^{m}y^{n}\\
&=-d(0, 0)+d_1(y)+d_2(x)
 +\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1} d(m,n)x^{m}y^{n}\\
&=-d(0, 0)+d_1(y)+d_2(x)
 +\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1} (d(m-1, n) + d(m-1, n-1)+d(m, n-1))x^{m}y^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Use the initial conditions
to get $d_1(y)$ and $d_2(y)$.

Split the last sum into
$\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1} d(m-1, n)x^{m}y^{n}
+\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1}  d(m-1, n-1)x^{m}y^{n}
+\sum_{m \geq 1}\sum_{n \geq 1} d(m, n-1)x^{m}y^{n}
$
and fiddle with the exponents
of $x$ and $y$
to get each sum
in terms of
$x, y, d(x, y),
d_1(y),$
and
$d_2(x)
$.

This will give you
a formula for
$d(x, y)$.